# How Can I Get Yesterday Record From Table and then SUM fields from Yesterday Record in Laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a table with 4 fields/columns A, B, C, D. Now I need to get last but one or yesterday record from the table and then SUM of A,B fields/column as Result1 and SUM of C,D fields/column as Result2. Please check the image for better understanding. Problem is that I am getting the yesterday data but aggregate SUM is not working.

```
$all = Corona::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->first();
 
 $Result = array(

     'Result1' => $all->map(function($all){ return $all->A; })->sum()+
                         $all->map(function($all){ return $all->B; })->sum(),                         
                         
     'Result2' => $all->map(function($all){ return $all->C; })->sum()+
                         $all->map(function($all){ return $all->D; })->sum()       
     );
```

[Table with expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p1Gf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **value** like following

```
->value(DB::raw("SUM(A + B) AS some_name"));
```

your query will be like following

```
$yourdate = "2020-08-02 07:24";
$stats = Corona::where('created_at', $yourdate)
                ->value(DB::raw("SUM(A + B) AS some_name"));
```

Comment: It SUMs all records of A, B and then add result A and B. I don't want that, I want, It will SUM only last but one record of A and B and return a result. Could you please check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p1Gf.png what I want.

Comment: you just need to pass your date in where condition...